# Exporting Excel in c# Numbers showing E+

Tags: c#, excel, export

when I export data to excel in c#, numbers are displaying 3.24234E+20 instead of "324234234234234000000". i want to display exact numbers in excel, how to format cells through c#.

[image: Export to excel]

In Excel format types "General format is showing like E+", but in Number format is showing exact numbers whatever is their.

Console Application ro export the excel file.

```
String strFilePath = "c:\file.csv";
List<string> lst = new List{"121826198369183", "3287456823568723", "23874523876528936589265"};

using (var file = File.CreateText(strFilePath))
{
    foreach (var arr in lst)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0) continue;
        file.Write(arr[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            file.Write(arr[i]);
        }
        file.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the cells for numbers. 
[Here's an example](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/10/15/excel-cell-values-formulas-formatting-csharp/#Formatting_cells)

The format strings can be used like in excel. If you want to keep preceeding zeros, you'll have to define a format like "00000000000000000". Excel will then always show 17 digits and add zeros in front of the number if it has less than 17 significant digits.

Comment: hi Marwie, if I format the cells to Number and if i have data like "00378464156142612" then i will lose begning zeros. i don't want  to lose any characters.

Comment: If you want to keep the preceeding zeros you have to put in a format with zeros instead of '#'. Since you're coming from c# you can dynamically calculate the total number of format zeros from the number of digits you want to show. In this case "00000000000000000".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you provide a bit more detail about how exactly you are doing the export. Any plugins etc?

If you are doing the HTML to XLS way then may I suggest you try applying the following style to every cell before you export?

```
mso-number-format:\@;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi I am not  doing any HTML to XML way, If you have code plase share with me

Comment: I have console application to export the excel. please find my post now I added code.

Comment: Right, so you are creating a text file with .xls extension. I think you will not be able to use the mso style formatting here. 

If your need is really a very small and quick app, then I suggest you try making an html with .xls extension.

If your need is a full-fledged app with thousands of records in an enterprise level report then I suggest you use a plug in such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: How to html with .xls extension in console application?\

Comment: Please try [this](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2004/03/20/Export-data-in-a-web-application-to-Excel-including-formulas-for-columns.aspx).